# What's wrong with this (simple) lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

There's something wrong with the captured variable, but I can't figure out what. The error I'm getting is

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘applyFunc(int, main()::<lambda(int)>)’
  applyFunc<int,int>(0,[=](int z) -> int{return z + xx;}); //error!
```

Any insight on what's wrong?

```
//given input x and function func, return func(x)
template <typename T, typename U>
U applyFunc( T x, U func(T) )
{
    return func(x);
}

int main()
{
    int xx = 2;
    applyFunc<int,int>(0,[](int x) -> int {return x + 1;}); //no error
    applyFunc<int,int>(0,[=](int z) -> int{return z + xx;}); //error!

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Fix with function object from < functional >.**

```
#include <functional>

template <typename RET, typename INPUT>
RET applyFunc( INPUT x, std::function<RET(INPUT)> func )
{
    return func(x);
}

int aFunc(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int xx = 4;
    applyFunc<int,int>(0,[](int x) -> int {return x + 1;});
    applyFunc<int,int>(0,[=](int z) -> int{return z + xx;});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's the thought I had, however I'm getting an error about the wrong number of template arguments.

Comment: Read the documentation of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: re. the edit, change to `std::function<RET(INPUT)>`

Comment: `std::function` would we way out of place in code lie this. It will make it "compile" and "run", but this is not the right way to go. This is not what `std::function` is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter `func` is declared as a regular function pointer. Lambdas are not regular functions. Yet lambdas are *convertible* to regular function pointers, but only if they have empty capture clause.

Lambda

```
[](int x) -> int {return x + 1;}
```

has empty capture clause, which makes it convertible to function pointer type `int (*)(int)`.

Lambda

```
[=](int z) -> int{return z + xx;}
```

has non-empty capture clause, which means that it is not convertible to a regular function pointer.

---

Your idea to use `std::function` will make your code compile and work. However, there is an inherent inefficiency in this approach. `std::function` is an implementation of type erasure technique based on run-time polymorphism. One of its main purposes is to facilitate switch from compile-time polymorphism to run-time polymorphism, thus reducing "templatization" of the code. Basically, by using `std::function` you agree to the run-time overhead hidden in `std::function` implementation in order to reduce the template-induced code bloat.

This issue does not apply to your specific code. Your template function is small and dependent on compile-time arguments in every aspect. Your function is purely conceptual and should dissolve (disappear) entirely in the resultant code. In such cases you *want* it to work through compile-time polymorphism. Bringing in `std::function` just to make it compile does not look like the right idea. This is shooting sparrows with a cannon and paying for the overhead.

What you could do instead (as the first step) is just add another template parameter for functor type

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename F>
U applyFunc( T x, F func )
{
    return func(x);
}
```

As the second step, you'd immediately notice that template parameter `U` is now excessive: it is implicitly brought in by the combination of `T` and `F`. By extracting this type from `F` you can rewrite your template as

```
template <typename T, typename F>
std::result_of_t<F(T)> applyFunc( T x, F func )
{
    return func(x);
}
```

(This can be further improved by using "perfect forwarding" features of the language.)

Note that this also enables full deduction of function template arguments by the compiler, so you will no longer have to specify them explicitly

```
int xx = 2;
applyFunc(0,[](int x) { return x + 1; });
applyFunc(0,[=](int z) { return z + xx; });
```

One can also note that we can even try to get rid of `T` as template parameter (extracting it from `F`), but I wouldn't do that. Keeping `T` flexible makes the template to support natural concept of function overloading.

Comment: I see. Can I use the function declaration in the function library to pass a lambda function with capture?

Comment: @roro: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you illustrate it with an example?

Comment: @roro: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot make comment to [markyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365443/markyxl%20markyxl) answer, so I will provide another one. Instead of specifying return type, you can use **auto** and **decltype**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U>
auto applyFunc(T x, U func) -> decltype(func(x))
{
  return func(x);
}

int main()
{
  int xx = 2;
  bool a = applyFunc<bool>(0,[](int x) -> bool {return x > 0;});
  bool b = applyFunc<bool>(0,[=](int z) -> bool {return z + xx > 0;});

  cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work, the only caveat is that you have to manually specify the return type of the lambda function:

```
//given input x and function func, return func(x)
template <typename RET, typename T, typename U>
RET applyFunc(T x, U func)
{
  return func(x);
}

int main()
{
  int xx = 2;
  bool a = applyFunc<bool>(0,[](int x) -> bool {return x > 0;});
  bool b = applyFunc<bool>(0,[=](int z) -> bool {return z + xx > 0;});

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will consider func to be an object of type U (templated as an int in main). func(x) will be a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, this will consider func to be an object of type U. Lambda functions are objects with operator (). func(x) will call this operator for you. The code complies fine, I checked it.

Comment: I get what you're saying now, I like this solution better when my return type matches my input type, but is more clunky otherwise. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I want the return type of the lambda function to be different from the input, I'd need three template variables.

Comment: Yes, I thought the return value should be the same. I modified my answer to allow different return type. You don't need to specify the other two template arguments, compiler will deduce them.